# xlDown not working as intended

Tags: vba, excel

I've followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzP8nO9UVvY) tutorial

In order to handle button action. I want to write data to new row every time, on button click, but ths code either overwrites existing data or write data to a new rows (and again overwrites it).

code :

```
Private Sub cmdUnesiUBazu_click()
     Sheet1.Activate

    Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select ' want to start write from C2 cell
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = txtSifraOsobe.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = txtImeIPrezime.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = txtAdresa.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = cboGrad.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = cboDrzava.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = txtDatumRodjenja.Value

  End Sub
```

Comment: I can't replicate this - that code works fine for me, although using actual references instead of `ActiveCell` and `Offset` would be much better.

Comment: I don't understand the line `ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value + 1`. Since you are using `Range("B2").End(xlDown)`, this is probably the last cell in the column. why take data from the next empty row. Unless you are sure its not empty

Comment: if you want to get the last row in Column B, you should probably use `Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Select`

Comment: @nightcrawler23
Works with your solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to refer to cells directly, instead of selecting them and referring to the `ActiveCell`.  Watch [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ)

It looks like you are trying to make a unique identifier (ID) to refer to your records.  But you are adding 1 to the empty cell below: `ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(`**1**`, 0).Value + 1` instead you should be adding 1 to the value of the cell above `ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(`**-1**`, 0).Value + 1`

```
Sheet1.Activate

With Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    .Value = .Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
    .Offset(0, 1).Value = txtSifraOsobe.Value
    .Offset(0, 2).Value = txtImeIPrezime.Value
    .Offset(0, 3).Value = txtAdresa.Value
    .Offset(0, 4).Value = cboGrad.Value
    .Offset(0, 5).Value = cboDrzava.Value
    .Offset(0, 7).Value = txtDatumRodjenja.Value
End With
```

Comment: Actually, in my project stands Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1, something get wrong when I copied code here. But it still acts strange, and , when there isn't any filled data , it writes to first row, and then it keeps overwriting it.

Comment: @MGKPIf you post a screenshot of the data I will explain why it is doing what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

If would be much tidier to avoid the `Activate` and cell by cell `Offsets`, ie perhaps:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range

Set ws = Sheets(1)
Set rng1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
rng1.Offset(1, 1).Resize(1, 7) = Array(Me.txtSifraOsobe, Me.txtImeIPrezime, Me.txtAdresa, Me.cboGrad, Me.cboDrzava, , Me.txtDatumRodjenja)
```